# Reseting Sort jQuery Table Sorter

Tags: jquery, html

I am using https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/ Table Sorter Plugin.

When I `reset` the filter using a button, and it works fine.

```
<button type="button" class="reset">View All</button>
<button class="search" type="button" data-column="0">Studio</button>
<button class="search" type="button" data-column="0">One Bedroom</button>
<button class="search" type="button" data-column="0">Two Bedroom</button>
```

However, When I am having a bad nightmare trying to `reset` the filter using a dropdown list.

```
<select class="mobileFilter"  id="">
     <option value="" disabled>FILTER BY</option>
     <option value="VIEW ALL">VIEW ALL</option>
     <option value="STUDIO" data-column="0">STUDIO</option>
     <option value="ONE BEDROOM" data-column="0">ONE BEDROOM</option>

</select>
```

I tried resetting the filter as guided in their documentation (https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-reset), but it doesnt seem to work.

```
$(function(){
  $("table").tablesorter({
    widgets: ["filter"],
    widgetOptions : {
      filter_reset : '.reset'
    }
  });
});
```

Here is the work so far https://jsfiddle.net/5kehm83d/ . It contains working example of `filter` and `reset` via buttons.

**EDIT**
I figured out one solution. We can just remove the `filter` text from the `input` box and trigger a `keyup()` function.

```
$('.tablesorter-filter').val('').trigger('keyup');
```

I am leaving this question open more proper answer if any.

Comment: Can you provide an working example ?

Comment: @Berkay https://jsfiddle.net/5kehm83d/ here is a working example of `filter`

Comment: @Berkay Hey, Thanks for your support. But I figured it out.